# Different pictograms for normal and selected state of tableView cells

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

Here's my setup. Table view with custom designed cell, reused many times. The layout is four UILabels and one UIImageView.

I load the cells in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, and inside it, after finding out which cell (data item) it is, I populate the labels with appropriate text from the datasource.

Also I have 7 pictograms. Each cell gets one of those pictograms, based on the cell's content (item type). The problem is, each pictogram exists in its normal version and its "selected" version. That means when the cell is selected, the design team has provided me with a modified version of pictogram with slightly different colours.

So for each cell I need to load `pictogram_normal` and `pictogram_selected` into the same cell so that the selected one is shown when the cell is selected.

How should I set this up?

Answer (score 0):

When  a cell is selected,change this cell's background imageview,then make other cell's background imageview to normal.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell* cell=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundView=[[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pictogram_selected.png"]] autorelease];
    cell.selected=YES;
    selectedIndex=indexPath.row;

    for(UITableViewCell* theCell in [tableView visibleCells]){
        if(![theCell isEqual:cell])
        {
            theCell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            theCell.selected=NO;
            [theCell.backgroundView removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
}
```

`selectedIndex` is a number which saved tableview's selectedindex.If you wanna save the selected status in tableview , use selectedIndex to make cell selected.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    ITableViewCell*   cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil] autorelease];
    cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    //your code here

    if(indexPath.row == selectedIndex)
    {
        cell.backgroundView=[[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pictogram_selected.png"]] autorelease];
        cell.selected=YES;
    }

    //your code here

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Sorry man, allocing a new UIimageView object for each cell is a bit too expensive :-/